# How to parse JSON data to PHP?

Tags: php, json

I am new to PHP and AngularJS. I want to get JSON data.

Chrome shows the data I post

```
{"sessionName":"1","computer":"2","quality":{"name":"LAN(very fast)"}}
```

I know that if I want to get sesstionName, it's:

```
$value = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
echo $value->sessionName;
```

How can I get quality value from PHP?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);`- it should be already parsed by php automagically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access like this

```
echo $value->quality->name;
```

Comment: You're right, that's simultaneity ! You were two seconds before, so I deleted mine.

Comment: Thank for your help , LorenzMeyer and Shankar Damodaran

Answer (score 1):

Eventually if you prefer to work with arrays instead of objects, my advice is to do:

```
$value = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
```

then you can see the result:

```
print_r($value['quality']);
```

Comment: Thank your for your segesstion , but I tried your it , still get nothing

Comment: This means that php://input is not what you expect it to be! Test it with `echo file_get_contents('php://input');`